# Woocommerce get billing state manually

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters, notifications

Im modifying the receipts for the email admin notifications with woocommerce filter "`woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order`" Im conditioning them to the state wich the order is billed. For this there is the method get_billing_state(), this works perfect sending the notifications but in the admin i got the error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_billing_state() on null.

Im assuming that I can call the billing state maually to put it in some way.

```
function tm_destinatario_condicionado_wc( $recipient, $order ) {

    $estados = array(
        'aguascalientes'        => 'AG',
        'baja-california'       => 'BC',
        // etc etc ...
    );

    // Get billing state 2 digits
    // This is what is causing the error
    $estado_siglas = $order->get_billing_state();

    // Get the keys of $estados by the value (wich is the 2 digit billing 
    // state) to get state name
    $estado_slug = array_search( $estado_siglas, $estados );

    // Gets the id of a taxonomy related to the state based on the name 
    // obtained from $estados theres a custon field containing the recipients
    $estado_id = get_term_by( 'slug', $estado_slug, 'estados' )->term_id;

    // get the custom field with the recipients
    $emails  = get_field( 'sucursal_email', 'estados_' . $estado_id ); 

    // Add the custom field content to the recipient
    $recipient .= ', ' . $emails; 

    return $recipient;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'tm_destinatario_condicionado_wc', 10, 2 );
```

I apreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid that error, you have to add something in your function like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'tm_destinatario_condicionado_wc', 10, 2 );
function tm_destinatario_condicionado_wc( $recipient, $order ) {

    // To avoid an error in backend
    if( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) return $recipient;

    $estados = array(
        'aguascalientes'        => 'AG',
        'baja-california'       => 'BC',
        // etc etc ...
    );

    // Get billing state 2 digits
    // This is what is causing the error
    $estado_siglas = $order->get_billing_state();

    // Get the keys of $estados by the value (wich is the 2 digit billing 
    // state) to get state name
    $estado_slug = array_search( $estado_siglas, $estados );

    // Gets the id of a taxonomy related to the state based on the name 
    // obtained from $estados theres a custon field containing the recipients
    $estado_id = get_term_by( 'slug', $estado_slug, 'estados' )->term_id;

    // get the custom field with the recipients
    $emails  = get_field( 'sucursal_email', 'estados_' . $estado_id ); 

    // Add the custom field content to the recipient
    $recipient .= ', ' . $emails; 

    return $recipient;
}
```

This should solve your issue definitively…

Comment: Thank you very much, i was conditioning it in the same way but just if it was not admin and it was not working but that way solved the problem. 